# Equality-constrained least-squares problem via Lagrange multipliers

Tags: statistics, regression, lagrange-multiplier, least-squares, quadratic-programming

I am taking a *Theory of Linear Models* class and got the following assignment:

> Solve the Least Squares Probem using Lagrange Multipliers.

We are in the 3rd week of this class so we have only covered the basics. I don't have much experience in this field and the problem statement is not too elaborate so I need some perspective. I have researched and all the information I can find is on Constrained Linear Models, some have what they call "linear constraints", like here:

---

[image]

---

Then again, it says "When we compare different models". Am I supposed to solve a problem with a linear constraint or is that something completely different?  Any tips to get me started would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

Given

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & \| \mathrm A \mathrm x - \mathrm b \|_2^2\\ \text{subject to} & \mathrm C \mathrm x = \mathrm d\end{array}$$

we define the Lagrangian

$$\mathcal L (\mathrm x, \lambda) := \frac 12 \| \mathrm A \mathrm x - \mathrm b \|_2^2 + \lambda^{\top} \left( \mathrm C \mathrm x - \mathrm d \right)$$

Taking the partial derivatives and finding where they vanish, we obtain the following linear system

$$\begin{bmatrix} \mathrm A^{\top} \mathrm A & \mathrm C^{\top}\\ \mathrm C & \mathrm O\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \mathrm x\\ \lambda\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \mathrm A^{\top} \mathrm b\\ \mathrm d\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Is there a version of it without forming the normal equation system?

Comment: @pinpon One possibility would be to solve $\rm C x = d$, whose solution space is parameterized by $\mathrm x_{\ln} + \mathrm V \eta$, and then rewrite as an unconstrained least-squares problem in $\eta$.

Comment: What do you mean by "is parameterized by xln+Vη"? what does the suffix "ln" stands for?

Comment: @pinpon Yes, clarification is in order. The subscript "ln" stands for "least-norm". In other words, the solution space is a hyperplane, and the point on this hyperplane closest to the origin (in the Euclidean norm) is a special particular solution called the least-norm solution. The columns of $\rm V$ span the hyperplane when it is shifted so that it passes through the origin. Take a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2102352/339790).

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I am not still sure I understood the whole procedure. First I solve for $\rm C x = d$ taking the least norm solution. Then I solve the system $A V \eta= b - A x_{ln}$ for $\eta$, being $V$ the row space of $C$. Is that correct?

Comment: Sorry being $V$ the null space of $C$

Comment: @pinpon Using SVD is the way to go. Once one has the least-norm solution and the null space of $\rm C$, then one can solve the unconstrained least-squares problem $$\text{minimize} \quad \| \mathrm A \mathrm V \eta - \left( \mathrm b - \mathrm A \mathrm x_{\text{LN}} \right)  \|_2^2$$ Taking the gradient and finding where it vanishes, one obtains the following normal equations $$\mathrm V^\top \mathrm A^\top \mathrm A \mathrm V \eta = \mathrm V^\top \mathrm A^\top \left( \mathrm b - \mathrm A \mathrm x_{\text{LN}} \right)$$

Comment: Thank you again, now is clear!

Comment: Why did you put to the Lagrangian function $\frac{1}{2}$? There is no  $\frac{1}{2}$ in the minimazing function. Thank you for the answer in advance.

Comment: @Laura Because it is convenient and legal. Once differentiated, the quadratic term is left alone — no pesky $2$ multiplier cluttering things.

Comment: Ok, but if I do not put the fraction there and will solve the problem without $\frac{1}{2}$ is it ok as well?

Comment: @Laura It's OK, but your Lagrange multiplier will be scaled (relative to mine).